# Ask for help chapter style in latex

Tags: memoir

how can a change in VZ15b chapter style, like the chapter is very small and I want to add some symbols in the line left and right the chapter please

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What's a `V215b` chapter style???

Comment: yes it is VZ15b

Comment: Yes, butt where is it described? I've never heard of it.